# How to give TFS CopyDirectory access to running agent or build controller

Tags: tfs, build, controller, msbuild, tfsbuild

I build a custom TFS build template with CopyDirectory activity. But somehow its throwing an error saying

> TF270002: An error occurred copying files from 'C:\MSBuilds\Project
>   Files\' to '\network shared drive\c$\'. Details: Access to the path
>   '\network shared drive\c$\' is denied.

How do I give copy access to my running agent or build controller whichever is applicable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TFS 2010 Build, constant drop location, random access issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23991455/tfs-2010-build-constant-drop-location-random-access-issue)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a permission issue, if your account of the build agent can access the network shared path.

The virus scanner sometimes causes these issues, especially on virtualized systems. Try to exclude the build folder and drop folder from the virus scanner that were installed on the build server and build agent.